# spacing when hyphen two words

Tags: hyphenation

When I tried to type mathematical terminologies, like `Hasse-Weil` theorem,
there is a minor thing which hurts my eyes.

The issue is the spacing between and after the hyphen, which you can see
in the following picture. The is almost no spacing before it, and there is
a (visually visible) "big" spacing after it.

Theoretically, I understand this is a correct design.
However, `emotionally`, I `DON'T LIKE` this.

Does this issue ever bother you before?
And if yes, how do you deal with it?

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}


\begin{document}

\noindent
Hasse-Tate\\
Hasse-Vitry\\
Hasse-Weil\\
Hasse-Yvye\\
\ \\
Hasse-Grothendieck

\end{document}
```

Comment: The font doesn't define kerning between the hyphen and uppercase letters. You have to add your own, if you want it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Computer Modern fonts define no kerning between the hyphen and uppercase letters, so if you want it you have to insert your own:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\?}[1]{\kern-.#1em }

\begin{document}

Hasse-Weil

Hasse-\?{02}Weil

Hasse-\?{04}Weil

Hasse-\?{06}Weil

Hasse-\?{08}Weil

Hasse-\?{10}Weil

Hasse-\?{12}Weil

Hasse-\?{14}Weil

\end{document}
```

[image]

For a semiautomatic version, add the same kern that would be inserted if the hyphen had been an A:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\?}[1]{% kerned hyphen
  \sbox0{A#1}\sbox2{A\kern0pt #1}%
  \kern\dimexpr\wd0-\wd2\relax
  #1%
}

\begin{document}

Hasse-\?Weil

Hasse-\?Tate

Hasse-\?Yvye

Hasse-\?Grothendieck

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will try it. However, do you think it would be better to adjust both the spacing before and after the hyphen, in order to get a balance adjustment.

Comment: @user565739 Personally, I wouldn't kern before the hyphen.

Comment: May you explain what "A" means in "the hyphen had been an A"?
Also in the semiautomatic code, how the kern is determined?

Comment: @user565739 `#1` stands for the next character; then I measure the width of `A#1` and of `A\kern0pt #1` in order to determine the kerning between the two letters. I changed the previous `{}` to `\kern0pt` because the former method doesn't work with LuaTeX.

Comment: Isn't `#1` the first argument? Do you mean `A#1` stands for the next character, rather than `#1`? Thanks again for your patience.

Comment: The `\?` macro absorbs the next character as its argument, which is used in place of `#1`.

Comment: So I still don't get what "A" is, as you wrote ``if the hyphen had been an A:''

Comment: In the case of `Hasse-\?Weil` I typeset boxes containing `AW` and `A\kern0ptW`; their widths differ by the kerning the font applies between A and W, so I can kern by this difference.

Comment: OK, understand it now. Just a final question, why you choose `A`? (just curious)

Comment: @user565739 It's the typical character other uppercase letters kern with.